# Использование dll в модуле node.js написанном C++

Tags: c++, node.js, dll

Есть модуль node.js написанный на С++ (с использованием N-api). Этот  модуль использует dll. Сборка проходит успешно, но при вызове функций в модуле ссылающихся на dll, программа перестает работать. (dll лежит в папке с проектом). При использовании статической библиотеки вместо dll, данной проблемы нет.
Можно ли в данном случае заставить модуль работать с dll?

Comment: Какие-нибудь сообщения об ошибках есть? Что мешает использовать статическую библиотеку?

Comment: Однозначно можно.

Comment: Никаких сообщений не выпадает, просто программа прекращает работу, как я понял по причине, что она не может найти реализацию функций в модуле.  В данном случае нужно добиться работы через dll. Может как то нужно указать путь к dll?

Comment: Разделяемая библиотека должна лежать рядом с файлом ‘.node’, т.е. с файлом, который вы получаете после компиляции.